# Como modificar (agregar mas datos) a un arreglo local desde otra función

Tags: c++, funciones

Cree un arreglo de datos de 5 * 5 el cual lo hice de manera local en una función llamada ver evento, lo siguiente que quiero hacer es agregarle mas datos desde otra función llamada registroEvento, pero estoy teniendo problemas al momento de llamar dicha variable

```
void verEvento() {
string infoEventos [5][5]={
        { "Hacketon ", "", "", " ", " "},
        {"Seguridad informatica", "",""," ", " "},
        {"Enero 12", "",""," "," "},
        {"cantidad de alumnos: 123", " ", " ", " "," "},
        {"1B"," ", "  ", " "," "}
};


for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
        if (infoEventos[i][j] != " "){
            cout << infoEventos[0][j] <<"\n"<<infoEventos[1][j] << "\n"<<infoEventos[2][j]<< "\n"<<infoEventos[3][j]<<"\n"<<infoEventos[4][j]<<"\n"<<"---------------"<<endl;
        }
    }
    i=3;
}


}
```

en la funcion anterior es donde cree la cadena pero quiero mandarla a llamar desde la siguiente funcion

```
void registroEvento() {
 }
```

las anteriores funciones son llamadas desde una funcion principal llamada main donde puse un switch para un menu

int main(){

```
int menu(){
int opc = 0;

do {
    cout << "Que desea realizar" <<endl;
    cout << "1 registro Evento"<<endl;
    cout << "6 salir"<<endl;
    cout << ": ";
    cin >> opc;

    switch(opc){
        case 1:
            registroEvento();
            break;

        case 5:
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Adios";
            return 0;
    }

} while (true);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Es imposible que una función pueda hacer uso de variables que han sido declaradas dentro de otras funciones, primero porque no son accesibles fuera de su ámbito donde fue creada (determinado por las mismas llaves del cuerpo de la función) y segundo porque esas variables van a existir el tiempo que dura la ejecución de la función, esto quiere decir que cuando la función termina la variable se destruye automáticamente y en el momento que llamas a `registroEvento`, pues infoEvento ya no existe, una solución sería declarar `infoEventos` como variable global, es decir, fuera de cualquier función incluida la función main.

```
const int FILAS = 5;
const int COLUMNAS = 5;

std::string infoEventos[FILAS][COLUMNAS] = {
    {"Hacketon","","","",""},
    {"Seguridad informatica","","","",""},
    {"Enero 12","","","",""},
    {"cantidad de alumnos: 123","","","",""},
    {"1B","","","",""}
};
```

De esta manera la hacemos accesible para todas las funciones de nuestro programa y no se destruye hasta que finalice todo nuestro programa, hecho esto, la función `verEvento` solo se queda con el ciclo for.

```
void verEvento(){
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
            if (infoEventos[i][j] != " "){
                std::cout<<infoEventos[0][j]<<"\n"
                         <<infoEventos[1][j]<<"\n"
                         <<infoEventos[2][j]<<"\n"
                         <<infoEventos[3][j]<<"\n"
                         <<infoEventos[4][j]<<"\n"
                         <<"---------------"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
        i=3;
    }
}
```

Lo siguiente seria `registroEvento`, que puede ser así.

```
int cont = 1;
int final = 4;

void registroEvento(){
    if(cont < final){
        std::cout<<"Ingrese dato 1: ";
        std::getline(std::cin,infoEventos[0][cont]);
        std::fflush(stdin);

        std::cout<<"Ingrese dato 2: ";
        std::getline(std::cin,infoEventos[1][cont]);
        std::fflush(stdin);

        std::cout<<"Ingrese dato 3: ";
        std::getline(std::cin,infoEventos[2][cont]);
        std::fflush(stdin);

        std::cout<<"Ingrese dato 4: ";
        std::getline(std::cin,infoEventos[3][cont]);
        std::fflush(stdin);

        std::cout<<"Ingrese dato 5: ";
        std::getline(std::cin,infoEventos[4][cont]);
        std::fflush(stdin);

        cont++;
    }
}
```

Me apoyo en las variables globales `cont` y `final` como índices de acceso a los elementos de la matriz `infoEventos` para evitar un desbordamiento por intento de acceso a elemento fuera de rango, por ejemplo si se llama a `registroEvento` una sexta vez cuando la matriz solo tiene capacidad para cinco.